# Как создать всевозможные сочетания элементов массива без их повторения?

Tags: php, mysql

есть 3 элемента

```
$nid=1515;
$date=Array
(
    [0] => 2017-07-26
    [1] => 2017-07-27
    [2] => 2017-07-28
    [3] => 2017-08-15
    [4] => 2017-08-16
    [5] => 2017-08-23
)
$time=Array
(
    [0] => 14:30
    [1] => 15:00
    [2] => 15:30
    [3] => 16:30
)
```

узнал что для того чтобы поместить сразу все значения в базу, через один запрос нужно, чтобы команда выглядела вот так:

```
INSERT INTO table (nid, date, time) VALUES (1,2,3), (2,5,6), (7,8,9) .....;
```

соответственно мои данные, которые будут присвоены VALUES должны иметь вид:

```
(1515, 2017-07-26, 14:30), (1515, 2017-07-26, 15:00),.....,(1515, 2017-08-23, 16:30);
```

подскажите как сформировать такую строку? подойдет ли для этого `foreach`?

Comment: а разве у вас в массивах есть повторы? Так-то для их удаления можно юзать array_unique(), а результат потом "склеить".

Comment: я имел в виду чтобы не получилось вот так (1515, 2017-07-26, 14:30), (2017-07-26, 14:30, 1515)

когда получится два и более вариантов с одинаковыми данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> подскажите как сформировать такую строку? подойдет ли для этого
>   `foreach`?

подойдет, причем, очевидно, двойной.

```
$nid = 1515;
$dates = [
    '2017-07-26',
    '2017-07-27',
    '2017-07-28',
    '2017-08-15',
    '2017-08-16',
    '2017-08-23',
];

$time = ['14:30', '15:00', '15:30','16:30'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (nid, date, time) VALUES ";
$values  = [];

foreach($dates as $d){
    foreach($time as $t){
        $values[] = "($nid, '$d', '$t')";
    }
}

$sql .= implode(',', $values);

print $sql;
```

При формировании строки запроса надо отдавать себе отчет в том, какие данные вы записываете, корректны ли они, и т.п. Для данных, содержащих пользовательский ввод, прямая подстановка в тело запроса - очень плохая практика.
Как уже было замечено в комментариях к соседнему вопросу, размер выполняемого запроса (длины текста запроса) тоже ограничен.

Comment: нет пользовательского ввода, это данные о бронировании, при том идет проверка от какого пользователя они поступили, если роль не админ, то при попытки записи данных будет ошибка.

Comment: Вспомнился еще один негативный момент оптовой вставки. Он, конечно, несколько спорный, но все же. Если в исходных данных допущена ошибка, ломающая запрос (например пробел лишний, или дата с 32 числом - всякое бывает), то при 1100 инсертах вставится все, кроме этой кривой записи, что можно залогировать и обработать, а в случае одного SQL - не вставится ничего и ошибку задолбаешся искать

Comment: @rjhdby да уж не задолбаешься (: метод деления пополам достаточно быстро найдет строку (: но да, сложнее чем при последовательной. С другой стороны плюс - не надо делать транзакцию, чтобы откатиться в случае ошибки (:

Comment: @teran деление пополам? При 1100 строках? Быстро!? :D Ну и не забываем, что таки придется этот метод еще реализовывать и при этом не запутаться, что уже вставилось, а что нет ;)

Comment: хотя кажется ошибся я, не лучший способ вставлять все данные в базу за одну итерацию, так как нельзя проверить содержится ли в базе уже такая строка или нет, соответственно, можно наплодить кучу дублей.
поэтому взял с двух ответов нужное и соединил вместе.)))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов от дублей есть уникальные индексы и первичные ключи. Но в случае нарушения, при такой вставке вся он будет отклонена.

Comment: @rjhdby ну искать ошибку деля пополам, естественно не про программную вставку :) в SQL managment studio если вдруг не вставилось, выделил половину мышью да выполнил, прокатило - хорошо удалил выделенное, нет дак вся вставка отклонена, уполовинил еще раз. Я подобной вставкой часто пользуюсь, когда из экселя данные надо в базу импортировать шустро, чтобы в мастере не настраивать ничего (: и самая частая ошибка (кои весьма редки вообще), это обычно нарушение ключей.

Comment: А из 1100 записей ваших половинить до единственной всего то грубо 10 раз, но до 1 и не надо,  на 16 строках уже будет видна ошибка, а это всего 6 делений пополам (я так и не понял откуда цифры 1100 взялась :D ) правда это все в случае единственной ошибки :)

Answer (score 1):

Собирать INSERT-запрос по кускам - это классический способ выстрелить себе в ногу. Не делайте так.

Используйте подготовленные запросы и по одной вставке за раз.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO table (nid, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $nid, $date_value, $time_value);

for($i = 0;$i < count($date); $i++){
foreach($data as &$date_value)
    foreach($time as &$time_value){
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: а в процедурном коде всё же лучше "выстрел в ногу" вместо множественных запросов в теле цикла?

Comment: почему $i < count($date) а не $i < count($time)? или это не имеет значения?

и что такое 'iss'?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов это пример, как надо делать запросы. Какой логикой руководствоваться при выборе элементов для вставки я так и не понял - у вас там массивы разного размера и как их связывать вы не рассказали

Comment: проясните про классический выстрел, мне как-то не очень ясно, какие тут могут быть минусы. При малом количестве строк смысла в этом, ясно дело, нет. но когда вставить надо тысячи записей, множественная вставка куда эффективней.

Comment: @rjhdby логика видимо была в постоянном `nid` для всех вставок, а потом перебор: первая дата + 4 времени, вторая дата + 4времени.

Comment: @teran начнем с отсутствия контроля входных данных, продолжим ограничениями на максимальную длину запроса и завершим теоретически возможной длинной транзакцией

Comment: @rjhdby эти массивы друг от друга не зависят, просто пользователь передает разное количество элементов: он может передать как 1 дату и несколько часов (соответственно количество строк должно быть 1*на несколько), может передать 40 дат и пару часов (соответственно в таблице должно появиться 80 строк)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов т.е. эти массивы имеют отношение все ко всем?

Comment: @rjhdby, данные могут быть и собственные, а не сторонние. контролировать можно (если надо) при построении запроса. Ограничение макс длины запроса - вещь известная, потому не проблема. Про транзакции хз.  В противовес - при 500 отдельных вставках вместо одной, лог БД тоже не рад будет, время вставки отличаться весьма прилично.

Comment: @rjhdby ну... наверное... не понимаю
это наверное декартово произведение должно получиться, когда в таблицу попадают всевозможные варианты...
к примеру у меня 2 массива в первом - 3 уникальные даты, во втором 2 уникальных времени в таблице должно занестись 6 строк (всевозможные сочетание даты и времени)

Comment: @teran на сервере идет проверка, от кого поступили данные. если роль не админ - ошибка. Можете подсказать как сформировать строку, которую я помещу в таблицу?

Comment: @teran не, ну понятно, что создать себе проблему, а потом мужественно ее победить - это наше все :) Но зачем? Ну и должен заметить, что "данные могут быть и собственные, а не сторонние" - это нут вот вообще никак не делает их лучше и безошибочней

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов поправил ответ

Comment: @rjhdby буду пробовать на свежую голову, но что такое 'iss' я так и не понял, нигде кроме скобок не фигурирует, он вообще нужен могу удалить?

Comment: @rjhdby вставка множества значений за раз это такой же инструмент для работы. При использовании надо отдавать себе отчет о всех плюсах и минусах применения при решении конкретной задачи. Говорить что это всегда плохой подход - не корректно. Проверка данных важна, но не во всех задачах. Данные могут быть провалидированы и до непосредственого импорта другими инструментами. Так что не понимаю, в чем тут вы видите проблему. Применяйте инструментарий по назначению и проблем не будет никаких.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов вы доку то почитайте по этой функции... `iss` означает, что первый параметр `integer`, а два последующих `string`

Comment: @teran это очень правильные рассуждения с точки зрения человека, который понимает, что он делает. Вам же не придет в голову дать школьнику боевую гранату для метания на уроке физкультуры

Comment: @teran можете предложить альтернативный ответ? все таки интересен и вариант с однократным обращением к базе